# Where can I start to create a REST API's that will manage job listings?

Tags: javascript, java, sql, eclipse, rest

I have an assignment to create a REST api's that will manage job listings and possible applicants, the program must be backed by an SQL database and I am a bit lost on where to start could someone please help me?

Comment: google dot com is popular

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can approach this in a lot of ways,

first of all you need to choose a backend language to use, this choice can either be driven by what languages you can actually use or some project requirements

here are some frameworks by popular languages:

- Java: Spring Boot
- Python: Django, Flask
- C#: .NET Core REST Api
- Javascript: Node.js -> Express.js

then you need to decide if you want to use some tools like SwaggerUi to show the endpoints

also depending on the level of complexity you want to achieve you may need to consider using an open relational mapping library (ORM) to handle the queries for you, an example for C# is EntityFramework, for other languages you can easily find equivalents by searching ORM

you are gonna encounter some CORS problems probably so do some research on that topic too, each framework has his own ways to handle CORS

I'm not gonna cover the security part on this answer but if you need to provide conditional access to the APIs you need to consider that too as you will need some way to check if the request is authorized, as this is usually done using Bearer tokens a quick research on that won't hurt!

Answer (score 1):

A very popular framework is Spring Boot: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

You can build REST-Endpoints and also connect to a MySQL Database using JPA.

Comment: I haven't watched this, but it seems to be related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZi44GOD8kY  And another one without Spring: https://blog.payara.fish/create-a-restful-web-service-with-payara-server-5.194-netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Many different programming have the capabilities to create RESTful APIs like:

1. NodeJS
2. Python
3. Java
4. .NET
   They all have different frameworks to create APIs, with different structures.

My recommendation would be to use a programming language you are familiar with, if none, it would be best to use Python, it is easy to learn with English-like-syntax.

Secondly, depending on how you want to structure your project, it would influence the language to use. Some factors like speed of the project or functionalities on the backend might influence the programming language you want to use. As well as integration with other languages.